# wordpress trying to use global $wpdb outside the loop completely... anyone have an idea how?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i am making a plugin - most of the plugin files are within the loop and has no problem with global $wpdb however i now have a use for ajax in a way that i need onsuccess message to return into a variable. if i do that on pages that are within the loop. the message returned by ajax are the whole page due to the way plugin works.

So i have to create a separate page that wouldn't be within the plugin frame. then send the ajax to that page

My problem is since its a separate page it doesn't include WP's file or functions and therefore i am unable to use global $wpdb.

Anyone has an idea on what do i need to include to be able to use it ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Never mind found a way to solve it.. Thanks for who ever read.

Comment: I think you might want to share your solution for anyone else who encounters this (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

well didn't think about that. 
There are probably better ways of doing this but this is how I did it.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require '/x/x/x/blog_main_dir/wp-blog-header.php';
```

And i find the true location by using

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

and pregmatch_replace to cut what i dont need..

Yes there are better ways but this is a fast one that works for my problem.

just to clarify this solution works for me, it might not work for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is 2 years late, but in case anyone searches for this...)

```
//Tells WordPress to only load the very basic components
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );

//Include the database code
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

//Now use the database
echo $wpdb->prefix;
```